# Why CommandName function will not execute on click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton, linkbutton

I have two buttons, inside a Gridview one button is a LinkButton the other is an ImageButton they are as follows:

```
<asp:LinkButton  id="lbd5" runat="server" Text='Click Me'CommandName="GetData" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>
<asp:ImageButton ID="bntimgEdit"  runat="server" ImageUrl="./images/Edit.png"  AlternateText="Edit" CommandName="GetData" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
```

And in the behind code I have this function:

```
protected void gvappts_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "GetData")
    {
        SiEdit.Visible = true;
        ////Get rowindex
        int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        //Get Row
        GridViewRow gvr = gvappts.Rows[rowindex];
        //Set the label value to be the time    
        Label lblApptSel  = gvr.FindControl("lblAppt") as Label;
        lblApptId.Text = lblApptSel.Text;
    }       
}
```

My question is, the **LinkButton** works fine no problem.
The **ImageButton** however, nothing happens, 
So can you NOT use `CommandName="GetData" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'` with ImageButtons?

An explanation as to what is the cause. I failed to mention in my question that my application is running on the MONO Project platform under Apache web server using mono-mod on a Debian server. In this environment the image button code will NOT run.

BUT... I put my application on a Microsoft IIS ASP.NET web server and as the comments suggested the code ran fine with no issues.

At the very least I can say somewhere between MONO or Appache is the cause.

Comment: Could you share your Page_Load code and DataBinding code?

Comment: Tested your code, it works just fine. Both the LinkButton and ImageButton work. (I did change `Text='Click Me'CommandName` to `Text="Click Me" CommandName` as it should be)

Comment: Your code looks fine